# Please! Kivy app Buildozer work on windows but not on Android

Tags: android, kivymd, buildozer

I can run main.py in windown... but when buildozer to apk, it not running in android.

Please help me <3

This is main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.toast import toast
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.core.window import Window
import cv2
from plyer import filechooser

class Dsmenu(MDBoxLayout):
    manager = ObjectProperty()
    menu = ObjectProperty()   
class Chupanh(Screen):
    def switch_camera(self):
        try:
            self.ids.camera.index = (0 if self.ids.camera.index == 1 else 1)
        except AttributeError:
            toast("Không tìm thấy camera")
            self.ids.camera.index = (0 if self.ids.camera.index == 1 else 1)
class Phantichdv(Screen):
    pass
class Anhluu(Screen):
    pass
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(Chupanh(name ='chupanh'))
sm.add_widget(Phantichdv(name ='phantichdv'))
sm.add_widget(Anhluu(name ='anhluu'))
class FingerPrintApp(MDApp):       
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "DeepPurple" 
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"

    def img_reload(self):
        self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('phantichdv').ids.image_shot.reload()
    def capture(self):          
        self.camera = self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('chupanh').ids.camera       
        while self.camera.export_to_png("capture_img.png"):         
            break
        self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('chupanh').ids.camera.play = False
        self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('phantichdv').ids.image_shot.source = "capture_img.png"
        self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('phantichdv').ids.image_shot.reload()
    def enhance_img(self):                 
        pass       
        
    def phantich_img(self):
        self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('phantichdv').ids.image_shot.source = "phantich_img.png"

    def show_save_img(self):
        self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('anhluu').ids.image_show.source = "phantich_img.png"
        self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('anhluu').ids.image_show.reload()
        
    def file_manager_open(self):
        raw_path = filechooser.open_file(title="Chọn ảnh chứa dấu vết đường vân",
                                                                filters=[("All", "*.*"),("JPEG", "*.jpg"),("PNG", "*.png"),("TIF", "*.tif"),("Bitmap", "*.bmp")])
        try:
            self.img = cv2.imread(raw_path[0])            
            # while cv2.imwrite("capture_img.png",self.img):
            while cv2.imwrite("capture_img.png",self.img):    
                break
            self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('chupanh').ids.camera.play = False
            # self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('phantichdv').ids.image_shot.source = "capture_img.png"
            self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('phantichdv').ids.image_shot.source = "capture_img.png"
            self.root.ids.manager.get_screen('phantichdv').ids.image_shot.reload()                        
        except IndexError:
            toast("Bạn chưa chọn file",duration=2)   
            
FingerPrintApp().run()
```

and this is fingerprint.kv

```
MDBoxLayout:
    id:screen
    orientation: 'vertical'    
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: 'FingerPrint APP'
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        anchor_title: 'left' 
        elevation: 10                
        right_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: menu.set_state("open")]]
    MDNavigationLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'     
        ScreenManager:
            id:manager        
            Chupanh:        
            Phantichdv: 
            Anhluu:
        MDNavigationDrawer:            
            id: menu
            Dsmenu:
                manager: manager
                menu: menu 
<Dsmenu>:
    name: "menu"
    orientation: "vertical"
    # padding: "10dp"
    spacing: "10dp" 
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: "310dp", "40dp"
        size_hint: None, None  
        # Image:
        #     size: "300dp", "200dp"
        #     pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5 , 'top': 1}
        #     source: 
    MDLabel:
        text: "   Tác giả: VĂN VŨ THIÊN - PC09 Quảng Nam"
        font_style: "Subtitle2"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 10
    MDLabel:
        text: "   Email: vanvuthien@gmail.com"
        font_style: "Caption"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 10
    MDLabel:
        text: "   SĐT: 033.5951.464"
        font_style: "Caption"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 10
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: "CHỌN ẢNH"
                on_release:
                    root.menu.set_state("close")
                    root.manager.current = "chupanh"
                    root.manager.get_screen('chupanh').ids.camera.play = True
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "image-search-outline"                
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: "PHÂN TÍCH DẤU VẾT"
                on_release:
                    root.menu.set_state("close")
                    root.manager.current = "phantichdv"
                    root.manager.get_screen('chupanh').ids.camera.play = False 
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "fingerprint"
            OneLineIconListItem:
                text: "ẢNH ĐÃ PHÂN TÍCH"
                on_release:
                    root.menu.set_state("close")
                    root.manager.current = "anhluu"
                    root.manager.get_screen('chupanh').ids.camera.play = False 
                IconLeftWidget:
                    icon: "content-save-all"
<Chupanh>:
    name: 'chupanh'         
    Camera:
        index: 0
        id: camera
        resolution: (600, 800)
        play: True                
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}  
    MDIconButton:                            
        icon: 'image-search-outline' 
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color 
        user_font_size: "18sp"
        elevation: 10           
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.2 , 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release: 
            app.file_manager_open()
            root.manager.current = "phantichdv"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                
    MDFillRoundFlatIconButton: 
        text: 'Chụp ảnh'       
        icon: 'camera-iris' 
        elevation: 10              
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5 , 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release: 
            app.capture()
            root.manager.current = "phantichdv"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
    MDIconButton:                            
        icon: 'camera-flip-outline' 
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color 
        user_font_size: "18sp"
        elevation: 10              
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.8 , 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release: root.switch_camera()  
<Phantichdv>:
    name: "phantichdv"
    Image:
        id: image_shot
        elevation: 10
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5} 
    MDLabel:
        text: "Thông số:"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.05 , 'center_y': 0.95}
    MDSlider:
        id: slider 
        size_hint_x: 0.4
        min: 0
        max: 100
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.03 , 'center_y': 0.90}
    MDLabel:
        text: "Âm bản:"
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.45 , 'center_y': 0.95}
    MDSwitch:
        id: amban
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.45 , 'center_y': 0.90}
        active: False
    MDRaisedButton:        
        text: 'Xử lý'                                   
        pos_hint: {'x': 0.7 , 'center_y': 0.92}
        elevation: 10             
        on_release:
            app.enhance_img() 
    MDIconButton:                            
        icon: 'keyboard-backspace' 
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color 
        user_font_size: "18sp"
        elevation: 10              
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.2 , 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release: 
            root.manager.current = "chupanh"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
            root.manager.get_screen('chupanh').ids.camera.play = True
    MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:        
        icon: 'fingerprint'
        text: 'Phân tích'                
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5 , 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release: app.phantich_img() 
    MDIconButton:                            
        icon: 'content-save-all-outline' 
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color 
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        user_font_size: "18sp"
        elevation: 10 
        text_color: 1,1,1,1              
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.8 , 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release:
            app.show_save_img() 
            root.manager.current = "anhluu"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
    MDProgressBar:
        id: prog
        type: 'indeterminate'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5 , 'center_y': 0.02} 
<Anhluu>:
    name: "anhluu" 
    Image:
        id: image_show  
        pos_hint: {'top': 1} 
    MDIconButton:                            
        icon: 'camera-iris' 
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color 
        user_font_size: "18sp"
        elevation: 10            
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.75 , 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release: 
            root.manager.get_screen('chupanh').ids.camera.play = True
            root.manager.current = "chupanh"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
    MDIconButton:                            
        icon: 'keyboard-backspace' 
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color 
        user_font_size: "18sp"
        elevation: 10              
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.25 , 'center_y': 0.1}
        on_release: 
            root.manager.current = "phantichdv"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

I made buildozer.spec with

requirements = python3,opencv-python,plyer,kivy==2.0.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip

and

android.permissions = CAMERA, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

logcat:

```
    09-24 15:13:58.661  1330  1365 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
09-24 15:13:58.661  1330  1365 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 10, in <module>
09-24 15:13:58.661  1330  1365 I python  :    File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/easy/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
09-24 15:13:58.661  1330  1365 I python  :  ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.easy/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/cv2/cv2.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
09-24 15:13:58.661  1330  1365 I python  : Python for android ended.
09-24 15:13:58.878  2089  3881 I ActivityManager: Process org.test.easy (pid 1330) has died: fore TOP
09-24 15:13:58.910  2089  2191 W ActivityManager: setHasOverlayUi called on unknown pid: 1330
```

Answer (score 0):

The error your facing is due to contradicting architecture of your app and the cv2 build. Change your opencv requirements from `opencv-python` to `opencv`.
So you requirements should be

`requirements = python3,opencv,plyer,kivy==2.0.0,https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip`

Then run `buildozer android clean` inside your project directory. Now if you recompile and run your app should work properly.

Comment: thanks so much. 
but i get a new bug: `jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Fail to connect to camera service java.lang.RuntimeException`

Comment: You need to request the camera permission both in the buildozer.spec file and also during runtime just before you instance the camera class. Check here for more info.
https://github.com/Android-for-Python/CameraXF-Example/blob/12a730789481491fb1d4f1ef61fd25a0795d06d4/main.py#L33